# Bottom OnClickListener always unresolved

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I have a simple button in my recyclerview, when clicked the first time it should make the text editable, when clicked the second time, it should confirm the change.  The problem I'm having is that I have the two onClickListeners set up, but they refer to each other, and the bottom one can always resolve the top one, but the top one can't resolve the bottom one.

**Recyclerview: bindIngredient**

```
fun bindIngredient(ingredient: ListIngredientsQuery.Item, clickListener: RecyclerViewClickListener) {

    val ocl1 = View.OnClickListener{
        //Text Editable
        view.ingEditText.setText(view.ingNameTV.text.toString())
        view.ingNameTV.visibility = View.GONE
        view.ingEditText.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        view.ingEditButton.text = "Confirm"
        view.ingEditButton.setOnClickListener(ocl2)

    }

    var ocl2 = View.OnClickListener {
        //Text Not Editable
        view.ingNameTV.text = view.ingEditText.text
        view.ingEditText.visibility = View.GONE
        view.ingNameTV.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        view.ingEditButton.setOnClickListener(ocl1)
        clickListener.onConfirmSelect(ingredient)
    }

    this.ingredient = ingredient
    view.ingNameTV.text = ingredient.name()
    view.ingEditButton.setOnClickListener(ocl1)
    view.veganSpinner.setSelection(Vegan.valueOf(ingredient.vegan().toString()).ordinal, false)
    view.gfSpinner.setSelection(GlutenFree.valueOf(ingredient.glutenfree().toString()).ordinal, false)
}
```

In this example the line

```
view.ingEditButton.setOnClickListener(ocl2)
```

errors because ocl2 is unresolved.  If I switch the order of the two onClickListeners being declared and initialized, the line

```
view.ingEditButton.setOnClickListener(ocl1)
```

errors because ocl1 is resolved.  I take this to mean that it won't look further down to find what it needs, it'll only rely on objects that have already been initialized.

Is there a way to fix this?  Is there a better way to do this?  I'm tempted to just put two buttons in the same spot, give them each their own onclicklistener and swap their visibility, but this seems like a waste of resources.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your objects before you use them.

```
fun bindIngredient(ingredient: ListIngredientsQuery.Item, clickListener: RecyclerViewClickListener) {
    val ocl1: View.OnClickListener
    val ocl2: View.OnClickListener

    ocl1 = View.OnClickListener{
        //Text Editable
        view.ingEditText.setText(view.ingNameTV.text.toString())
        view.ingNameTV.visibility = View.GONE
        view.ingEditText.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        view.ingEditButton.text = "Confirm"
        view.ingEditButton.setOnClickListener(ocl2)
    }

    ocl2 = View.OnClickListener {
        //Text Not Editable
        view.ingNameTV.text = view.ingEditText.text
        view.ingEditText.visibility = View.GONE
        view.ingNameTV.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        view.ingEditButton.setOnClickListener(ocl1)
        clickListener.onConfirmSelect(ingredient)
    }

    this.ingredient = ingredient
    view.ingNameTV.text = ingredient.name()
    view.ingEditButton.setOnClickListener(ocl1)
    view.veganSpinner.setSelection(Vegan.valueOf(ingredient.vegan().toString()).ordinal, false)
    view.gfSpinner.setSelection(GlutenFree.valueOf(ingredient.glutenfree().toString()).ordinal, false)
}
```

However, **it would be better if you just used one `OnClickListener`**. You can simply save which state you are in, and when the button is clicked, you just check which state you are in, perform your action, and then change the state. This way you don't have to worry about switching your listeners, which can get messy.

Comment: the onClickListener on top still errors, saying olc2 must be initialized.  I think I'll start working in the direction of the one onClickListener